# Collection engine for Production

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout

I am currently using Meilisearch with Scout and I came across this part where the Laravel Documentation says for Local development we could use `collection` method. I am wondering what would be the outcome if i have collection method for production environment as well. Has anyone tried it for production environment ?

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout#local-development)

Edit:

I got two indexes.

- One index will not exceed 10,000 records for a year or so
- My records for the other index would not exceed 30,000 records per month

Comment: I haven't tried, but AFAIU the collection engine will call your database each time according to your search query which will cause extra load on DB and server also it might keep all 10000(or what number comes after filter) records in memory and would also affect server performance.

Comment: Thank you @iamab.in for the clarification. Seems it is not the best practice to go with the collection engine for production as it will bring CPU strikes in my Database even with a cache layer or auto scaling.